# Django serializer gives 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' error

Tags: python, django, json

I am trying to make Django view that will give JSON responce with earliest and latest objects. But unfotunately it fails to work with this error.

```
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I have other serialization and it works.

Here is the code.

```
def get_calendar_limits(request):
    result =  serializers.serialize("json", Session.objects.aggregate(Max('date'), Min('date')), ensure_ascii=False)
    return HttpResponse(result, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

Thanks a lot beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

```
objects= Session.objects.aggregate(Max('date'), Min('date'))
print [ type[o] for o in objects ]
result =  serializers.serialize("json", objects, ensure_ascii=False)
```

You might want to just run the above in interactive Python as an experiment.

What type are your objects?  Is that type serializable?

Comment: You are right, there objects are not serializable. 

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error when trying to serialize an object that is not derived from Django's Model

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I need to make my own serializer to serialize non-Django models.

I solved this by just having a JSON template as I only needed this for one small bit.

Answer (score 1):

Python has "json" module. It can 'dumps' and 'loads' function. They can serialize and deserialize accordingly.